# Como evitar registros duplicadados al usar IdentityUser en .NET Core

Tags: identityuser

Cómo puedo evitar o capturar de manera adecuada el error de IdentityUser cuando intento registrar un usuario que ya existe, usando como llave o indice unico el campo "Identificacion". Cómo puedo validar antes que el usuario no existe, ya que obtengo el mensaje:
**SqlException: No se puede insertar una fila de clave duplicada en el objeto 'dbo.AspNetUsers' con índice único 'IX_AspNetUsers_Identificacion'. El valor de la clave duplicada es (0801196704909). Se terminó la instrucción.**
He intentado lo siguiente antes de crear el registro de Usuario:

```
            ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            Usuario usuario1 = context.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Identificacion == usuarioVM.Identificacion);
            if (usuario1 != null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("UsuarioDuplicado", "Ya existe un Usuario con esta Identidad");
                return View(usuario1);
            }
```

Pero me devuelve el siguiente mensaje:
**InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.**

Mi ApplicationDbContext es el siguiente:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext()
        {

        }
```

Agradezco su tiempo.
Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes 2 posibilidades

1. Crear el db context de esta manera

```
var opt1 = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>().UseSqlite(@"aqui_connection_string").Options;
//Reemplaza useSqlite por la base de datos que tu ocupes. Ejemplo UseSqlServer para SQL  Server

ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext(opt1)
```

2. Ocupar Inyección de dependencias

En .net 6 o superior, en el Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ID_en_appsetting.json")));
```

En .net 5 hacia abajo, en startup.cs en ConfigureServices

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("connection_string")));
```

Luego en el controlador, colocar el constructor de esta manera:

```
public class MiControlador: Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public MiControlador(ApplicationDbContex tcontext)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
```